# Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.0 to 2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, migration, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I'd like to migrate from `ASP.NET Core 2.0` to 2.1.
But I get this error, when I build the project.

> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.0' has a package type
>   'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project 'Jahan.Beta.Web.App'.

How can I solve it?

**csproj file:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName></SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider></SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath></SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath></SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Pages\**" />
    <Content Remove="Pages\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Pages\**" />
    <None Remove="Pages\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove=".bowerrc" />
    <None Remove="Styles\theme.less" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Styles\theme.less">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\Admin\Data\" />
    <Folder Include="Content\css\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\css\Admin\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\images\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="FontAwesome" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="jQuery.Validation" Version="1.16.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npm" Version="3.5.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq.Dynamic.Core" Version="1.0.6.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Twitter.Bootstrap" Version="3.0.1.1" />
 </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\css\blog-post.css" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap-grid.css.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap-grid.min.css.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap-reboot.css.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.bundle.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.bundle.js.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.bundle.min.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js.map" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js" />
    <None Include="wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js.map" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, previous to .NET Core 2.1, you had to include the EF Core tooling explicitly via a package reference, whereas now, it comes in via the EF Core package itself. That trips a lot of people up when migrating, as you need to remove this package, or you get conflicts from different versions of the tooling being referenced.

However, here, you not only don't have a package reference for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet`, but you don't even have a package reference for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`. As such, it makes no sense why you'd be getting *any* exception related to anything to do with EF Core.

I would normally assume that this exception, then, is actually coming from another project via reference, but you don't even have any project references here. Are you sure you've posted the right project?

Also, FWIW, do not include client-side libraries via NuGet. Those packages are only for ASP.NET MVC. At best, they just won't even do anything useful in an ASP.NET Core project, and at worse they can actually cause your build to fail.

Client-side libraries are included via either LibMan or npm. Using npm is the better approach, but you'll also need to incorporate either webpack or gulp to actually copy/compile the node libraries into your `wwwroot/lib` directory.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure! I have only one project in my solution('Jahan.Beta.Web.App').

Comment: There there's something seriously wrong with your project because EF Core isn't even part of this. You can try deleting your project's bin and obj directories and then rebuilding - maybe there's something stuck. Other than that, I don't know what to tell you other than just create a new project from scratch and attempt to move just the relevant code over into that.

Comment: I've done already. I think, I should create a new project from scratch...